# What to do with questions which are duplicated from another site?

Tags: discussion, exact-duplicates

[This recent question](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/27130/uniquely-satisfying-puzzle) is identical to a puzzle I posed on Puzzling.SE [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/52154/a-very-unique-chess-puzzle).

What, if anything, should be done?

Answer (score 3):

This happens from time to time; it's unavoidable when Stack Exchange sites have overlapping scopes. Here is another instance:

- [Five Knights Problem](https://chess.stackexchange.com/q/1719/7297)
- [The same problem on Puzzling Stack Exchange](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/61140/11110)

Now, if the author of the questions copied it without [properly attributing it](/help/referencing), attribution should be added (please don't assume malice, not everybody is aware of the rules). But given the picture in the [first version of the question](https://chess.stackexchange.com/revisions/27130/1), that doesn't seem to be the case. (If anything, it looks like it's copied from somewhere else.)

You left a comment linking to your question on Puzzling, which is not required, but nice to generate some traffic. I've posted a link back; some users here might not be aware that a Puzzling site exists and vice versa.

Comment: The questions you linked are actually completely different. The (current) top rated answer of the chess SE question does not answer the OP's question; Noam Elkies' answer (the Korolkov study) seems more correct.

Comment: Ah, you're right. Too bad, I'll have to find another example. The following one involves Chess but not Chess.SE: I posted [this Movies.SE question](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/87788/20215) without knowing [this one](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/q/11322/12315) existed on BoardGames.SE. I only looked here ...